# How to get nested nodes using pyyml

Tags: python, yaml, devops, pipeline, ado

I've many yml (ADO devops) files that are different each ones. It means that I cannot query nodes/childs using a fixed tree structure.
I have to get the AzureKeyVault@2 "- task:" stanza that could be on different levels and could be on different childs, on different subtree indented.

Is there a way to extract the task attributes using pyyml when I cannot know the exact yml structure? The task is always named "AzureKeyVault@2"

```
....
....
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  displayName: Reading KVault
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: PIPPO       
    KeyVaultName: PLUTO
    SecretsFilter: '*'              
    RunAsPreJob: true
...
...
```

I've tried this demo code but it doesnt work

```
with open("example.yaml", "r") as stream:
    prime_service = yaml.safe_load(stream)

params = set()
for key in prime_service.keys():
    print(key)
    params.update(prime_service[key]["task"])
print(sorted(params))
```

Comment: The [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) format looks completely different from the [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) format. You have YAML not YML/yml

Answer (score 0):

You should recursively walk over your data structure and look for a value "AzureKeyVault@2".

In this example I use `ruamel.yaml` as it support the YAML 1.2 spec (from 2009) and
supports more than PyYAML even when just parsing YAML 1.1 documents. You should be able to do the same with PyYAML.

As there could be multiple keys 'AzureKeyVault@2' I append all such keys found to a list,
you can then decice to throw an error, take the first item, or some other action.

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

def find_task(d, name, result):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if name in d.values():
            result.append(d)
        else:
            for k, v in d.items():
                find_task(v, name, result)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for item in d:
            find_task(item, name, result)



yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
input = Path('example.yaml')

data = yaml.load(input)

tasks = []
find_task(data, 'AzureKeyVault@2', tasks)
assert len(tasks) == 1
print('>>> found <<<')
yaml.dump(tasks[0], sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
>>> found <<<
task: AzureKeyVault@2
displayName: Reading KVault
inputs:
  azureSubscription: PIPPO
  KeyVaultName: PLUTO
  SecretsFilter: '*'
  RunAsPreJob: true
```